# Search content from all views in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have over a 300 views in an Oracle database.

I am looking for a string in the view result. For example, I want to look for "Admission Possible" in the view resultset.

Is there any query which can scan all the views output and get me the list of all the views which will have this string.

PS: I am not looking for any string in the create view SQL command.I want it like this:

```
Select * from vw_ABC
```

should have one+ columns which has this string.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Such a code should browse all views and their `VARCHAR2` columns (as you're searching for a string) and display view name, column name that contains that value and number of occurrences. See if it helps.

Views in my schema:

```
SQL> select view_name from user_views;

VIEW_NAME
------------------------------
VEMP
VTEST
```

One of them contains string you're looking for:

```
SQL> select * from vtest;

NAME
------------------
Admission Possible
```

Code & the result:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_str  VARCHAR2 (500);
  3     l_cnt  NUMBER := 0;
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT u.table_name, u.column_name
  6                     FROM user_tab_columns u, user_views t
  7                    WHERE     u.table_name = t.view_name
  8                          AND u.data_type in ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR2'))
  9     LOOP
 10        l_str :=
 11              'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '
 12           || cur_r.table_name
 13           || ' WHERE '
 14           || cur_r.column_name
 15           || ' like (''%Admission Possible%'')';
 16
 17        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (l_str)
 18           INTO l_cnt;
 19
 20        IF l_cnt > 0
 21        THEN
 22           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 23              l_cnt || ' : ' || cur_r.table_name || '.' || cur_r.column_name);
 24        END IF;
 25     END LOOP;
 26  END;
 27  /
1 : VTEST.NAME

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks.. but this doesnt seem to be working. This query is returning all the tables even if there are no records in the view output.

Comment: Basically, this query for cursor has no records:                                                     SELECT u.table_name, u.column_name
                   FROM user_tab_columns u, user_views t
                  WHERE     u.table_name = t.view_name
                        AND u.data_type = 'VARCHAR2'. I dont have access to the tables. It is the finance system that I am trying to access through views.

Comment: Maybe column's datatype is CHAR (not VARCHAR2). I edited the answer and added some more info, along with sample data and the output. It *works* for me, should for you too.

Comment: select view_name from user_views doesnt return anything. I used this : select table_name,column_name from all_tab_columns where (data_type = 'VARCHAR2' or data_type = 'CHAR') and owner = 'MYUSER'. Still no expected result.

Comment: Try ALL_VIEWS and ALL_TAB_COLUMNS instead; include OWNER.

Comment: Another option is to use `DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML` and `EXTRACTVALUE` directly in select from all_tab_cols to get tabular results and without PL/SQL.

Comment: @DPS - is MYUSER the account you're connecting to? If so, then you've already established it doesn't own any views (nothing in USER_VIEWS). What you need to pass to ALL_VIEWS.OWNER is the name of the schema which owns the views you're interested in; alternatively, don't specify the owner positively but filter out views owned by SYS, etc.

Comment: yes, myuser is the owner.  The cursor doesnt seem to get the right result. I am not much into Oracle syntax/ queries. Could you please guide me how to use the other options you mentioned. Though I am not sure if I might be having permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    l_cnt integer;
begin
    for rec in (
        select 
           col.owner as schema_name,
           col.table_name, 
           col.column_name,
            col.data_type,
           'select count(1) from ' || col.owner || '.' || col.table_name  || ' where lower(' || col.column_name || ') like ''%addmission possible%''' as str
        from 
            all_tab_columns col
            inner join all_views v on (col.owner = v.owner and col.table_name = v.view_name)
        where
            col.data_type in ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR', 'VARCHAR2', 'NCHAR', 'NVARCHAR2')
            and col.owner not in 
                (
                    'ANONYMOUS','CTXSYS','DBSNMP','EXFSYS', 'LBACSYS', 
                    'MDSYS', 'MGMT_VIEW','OLAPSYS','OWBSYS','ORDPLUGINS', 'ORDSYS',
                    'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA','SYS','SYSMAN','SYSTEM', 'TSMSYS','WK_TEST',
                    'WKPROXY','WMSYS','XDB','APEX_040000', 'APEX_PUBLIC_USER','DIP', 
                    'FLOWS_30000','FLOWS_FILES','MDDATA', 'ORACLE_OCM', 'XS$NULL',
                    'SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR', 'SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR', 'PUBLIC',
                    'OUTLN', 'WKSYS', 'APEX_040200'
                )
        order by col.owner, col.table_name, col.column_id
    ) loop
        execute immediate (rec.str) into l_cnt;

        if l_cnt > 0 then
            dbms_output.put_line(rec.schema_name || '.' || rec.table_name || '.' || rec.column_name || ' has match');
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Thanks.

Comment: I dont want to find a column. But I want to find the content of the column. This query wont help. This will give me names of columns. If the column A from view ABC contains this text "Admission Possible", then it should be listed.

Comment: @DPS - I updated the post after your comment - please try.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for all the efforts. I ran the query but it ran for more than 2 hours and still running. I have a huge list of views, probably that could be the reason. So I guess I need to do manual search that would be faster, bcz I need to look for a lot of values.